# "Unexpected EOF while parsing" after a "try" statement

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm really, *really* new to Python and was making a small test program.

Here is my code:

```
def start ():   
    print ("This is where text would be")   
    prompt_sta ()

def prompt_sta ():  
    prompt_0=raw_input("Input a Command: ")  
    try:  
        if prompt_0 == 'Okay':                             
           next_screen ()  
        else:   
            print ('Type Okay.')   
            prompt_sta ()
```

when I try to run it I get the "Unexpected EOF while parsing" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the EOF error, you can just get rid of that try: like so

```
def start ():   
    print ("This is where text would be")   
    prompt_sta ()

def prompt_sta ():  
    prompt_0=raw_input("Input a Command: ")  

    if prompt_0 == 'Okay':                             
        next_screen ()  
    else:   
        print ('Type Okay.')   
        prompt_sta()
```

You can also just add an except clause, as Fernando said, if you still want to use try:

Answer (score 6):

The `try` needs an `except` clause.

Comment: This is the valid answer, simply add an except clause after the end of the try clause.
def start ():   
    print ("This is where text would be")   
    prompt_sta ()

def prompt_sta ():  
    prompt_0=raw_input("Input a Command: ")  
    try:  
        if prompt_0 == 'Okay':                             
           next_screen ()  
        else:   
            print ('Type Okay.')   
            prompt_sta ()   
   except:
      print("error")

Answer (score 1):

You need an except after the try. It's just a small syntax error; the eof comes from the python parser before it executes the code.

```
def start ():   
    print ("This is where text would be")   
    prompt_sta ()

def prompt_sta ():  
    prompt_0=raw_input("Input a Command: ")  
    try:  
        if prompt_0 == 'Okay':                             
           next_screen ()  
        else:   
            print ('Type Okay.')   
            prompt_sta ()  
    except Exception as ex:
        print (ex)
```

Here's the link to docs just to save a quick google:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html